# Equivalents of the Axiom of Choice in Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, axiom-of-choice

I've read on [n-Category Café](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/) that the following statements are equivalent:

1. The Axiom of Choice
2. For any discrete set $X$ and any group $G$, the cohomology $H^{1}(X,G)$ vanishes.

I was wondering what are the others equivalences of the axiom of choice in algebraic topology of 'that kind'.